# Copy value of div and put in it another div

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how i am suppose to copy the value of a div (for instance, the first one), and paste it to a second div via a mouse click event.

**Workflow**:

1. Click on the first div (to copy the value number 1)
2. If i click again, it will become 2, if i click again, it will become 3 and so forth.

I'm looking forward to seeing your response.

**Example** : [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjGrE.jpg)

ok

from copying here:

```
                  <li class="active">
                    <a href="#"  on-click="chip_amnt">
                      <img src="chip.jpg" alt="">
                      <span>250</span>
                    </a>
                  </li>

                  <li class="active">
                    <a href="#"  on-click="chip_amnt">
                      <img src="{{image_url}}" alt="">
                      <span>500/span>
                    </a>
                  </li>

                  <li class="active">
                    <a href="#"  on-click="chip_amnt">
                      <img src="{{image_url}}" alt="">
                      <span>100</span>
                    </a>
                  </li>
```

to here:

```
            <li class="">
                  Player Pair
                </li>
                <li class="">
                  Tie
                </li>
                <li class="">
                  Banker Pair
                </li>
                <li class="">
                  Player
                </li>
                <li class="">
                  Banker
                </li>
```

Comment: Showing your codes will help you a lot to get quick responses.

Comment: Hi suresh,

already posted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**1. give an id on each div for make it easy**

```
<div id="div1">Something here</div>
<div id="div2">Empty or something else</div>
```

**2. selection**

```
const div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
const div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
```

**3. addEventListner**

```
div1.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  div2.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML;
});
```

**example:**
http://jsbin.com/zasagerafi/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

You did not post your code.This is my assumption that you expecting like this. Just try the below one:

```js
$(function(){
$('.firstdiv').on('click',function(){
$('#store').text($(this).text());
});

$('.seconddiv').on('click',function(){
if($(this).text()){
$(this).text(parseInt($(this).text())+1);
}
else{
$(this).text($('.firstdiv').text());
}
});
});
```

```css
div{
border:1px solid;
width:100px;
height:100px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='firstdiv'>1</div>
<div class='seconddiv'></div>
<textarea id='store' style='display:none;'></textarea>
```

Comment: this is not doing what the guy describes :)

Comment: there is no border..this is exactly working what he asked

Comment: Hi guys,

already posted teh code of mine. need your help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Read the requirements again :))
> Click on the first div (to copy the value number 1)
> If i click again, it will become 2, if i click again, it will become 3 and so forth.

Comment: you are right..let me update.Now he posted the code @bluehipy

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function(){
var d1 = document.getElementById("d1"),
    d2 = document.getElementById("d2"),
    tmp;
    
    d1.onmousedown = function(){
      tmp = Number(this.innerHTML);
    };
    
    d2.onmousedown = function(){
      var v = (Number(this.innerHTML) || 0) +(tmp || 0);

      v && (this.innerHTML = v);
    }

})();
```

```css
div{border:1px solid;width:200px;height:200px; float:left;}
#d1{border-color:red;}
#d2{border-color:blue;}
```

```html
<div id="d1">
 1
</div>
<div id="d2">
</div>
```

Comment: uhm this is working weird, the teh with the red box should be the one that increments, not the other way around. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tmp=0;

function chip_amnt(o){
  tmp = Number(o.innerText);
}

function chip_provide(o){
  var value = (Number(o.innerHTML) || 0) + (tmp || 0);
  
  value && (o.innerHTML = value);
  
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="active">
  <a href="#" onclick="chip_amnt(this)">
    <img src="chip.jpg" alt="">
    <span>250</span>
  </a>
</li>

<li class="active">
  <a href="#" onclick="chip_amnt(this)">
    <img src="{{image_url}}" alt="">
    <span>500</span>
  </a>
 </li>
<li class="active">
  <a href="#"  onclick="chip_amnt(this)">
   <img src="{{image_url}}" alt="">
   <span>100</span>
  </a>
</li>
</ul>
to here:
<ul>
<li class="" onclick="chip_provide(this)">
  Player Pair
</li>
<li class=""  onclick="chip_provide(this)">
  Tie
</li>
<li class=""  onclick="chip_provide(this)">
  Banker Pair
</li>
<li class=""  onclick="chip_provide(this)">
  Player
</li>
<li class=""  onclick="chip_provide(this)">
  Banker
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you so much! not testing it yet but this is how i want it to be. thank you all guys, thanks Man! cheers..